# Segmentation fault when trying to assign frame ethh->h_dest on C++ Raw socket

Tags: c++, c, ethernet, raw-sockets

I'm trying to build a raw socket and I've built a structure to have every header : ETH, IP, etc.
I just started by assigning ETH field but when I run just this part of code, I get segmentation fault:

```
typedef struct Network_frame_test{
  unsigned char  dst_mac_addr[CONF_MAC_ADDRESS_SIZE];
  unsigned char  src_mac_addr[CONF_MAC_ADDRESS_SIZE];
  struct ethhdr         *ethh;
  struct iphdr          *iph;
  struct udphdr         *udph;
  unsigned char          buffer[ SIZE_BUFFER ];
} Network_frame_test;

int main(void)
{
  Network_frame_test frame_test;

  const unsigned char message[] = {'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a'};
  int message_size = sizeof(message)/sizeof(message[0]);
  printf("messge size : %d", message_size);

  unsigned char* sendbuff;
  printf(" message %.2x", message[0]);

  memset(&sendbuff,0,43);
  printf(" %d", 0);
  for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
  {
    frame_test.dst_mac_addr[i] = message[i+6];
  }
  frame_test.ethh = (struct ethhdr *)(sendbuff);  
  for(int i=0; i<CONF_MAC_ADDRESS_SIZE; i++)
  {
    frame_test.ethh->h_dest[i] = frame_test.dst_mac_addr[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sendbuff is a pointer to a char, not allocated or anything. By using memset on its address, you set its value to 0, which means a null pointer. Later on you assign it to frame_test.ethh, and try to access it. I believe that is where you see the issue.

Why is sendbuff an unsigned char pointer and not simply of type
struct ethhdr?
Also, why is the memset used for 43 bytes? I'd change it to be the size of struct ethhdr.
After that, simeply use
frame_test.ethh = &sendbuff;

```
...
struct ethhdr srndbuff:
memset(&sendbuff, 0, sizeof(sendbuff));
...
frame_test.ethh = &sendbuff
...
```

If you have to use it with unsigned char, then:

```
#DEFINE SIZE 43 /* or sizeof(struct ethhdr) */
...
unsigned char sendbuff[SIZE]; 
memset(sendbuff, 0, SIZE);
...
frame_test.ethh = (struct ethhdr *)(sendbuff);
...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track, here, but your answer needs improvement. The `sendbuff` is, indeed, a pointer but it doesn't point to anything. Also, the `&` needs to be removed in the call to `memset`. Maybe consider improving or re-writing your answer, so that it actually includes a working solution.

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. Kinda new to actually writing answers. I will try to make it look prettier. Added a suggestion.